# Angular2 + Meteor: How to use fakeAsync calls in component tests

Tags: angular, unit-testing, mocha.js, angular-meteor

I would like to test some Router logic in a component test (in an `angular2-meteor` project) and therefore I wanted to use `fakeAsync(...)`. As a result, I am getting the following error in the browser when running `npm test`:

```
Error: Expected to be running in 'ProxyZone', but it was not found.proxy.js
```

Having searched the web for similar issues I found https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/11230. It suggests that `zone.js/mocha-patch` is already available to wrap the tests in an appropriate Zone.

If I import `mocha-patch` in `init.test.js` then I get the following error:

```
TypeError: mochaOriginal.beforeEach is undefined
```

I assume it is too early to use mocha-patch in `init.test.js`.

How should I use it in an angular-meteor project (based on angular2-meteor-base boilerplate)?

Thanks for any help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this before, for my case, I put fakeAsync to wrap describe call back function instead of wrapping "it" call back function 
Ex:
Instead of this:

```
describe('text1', fakeAysnc(() => {}))
```

You should do this:

```
 describe('text1', () => {
       fakeAysnc(it('text2', ()=>{
          //enter code here
          tick()
          //enter code here
      })
    })
```